# Doubled Skype window when clicking notification in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, skype, notifications, windows-10-v1903

I have a weird experience with Skype installed on one of my Windows 10 1903-based computers.

Whenever:

- I have Skype opened and minimised to tray bar (notification area / clock),
- I see some Skype notification and click it,

Skype brings back its window and then opens another one, an exact copy, over that one:

[image]

The second "copy" of main Skype windows (opened after clicking notification) is not operable at all.

I cannot:

- react with any image (clicking "react to this message" brings no effect),
- switch to another chat using left sidebar (clicking brings no effect),
- write anything in current chat, etc.

This happens only:

- on one of my PCs, all others (with the same Skype and Windows version) works OK and opens only one copy of main Skype window after clicking a notification,
- when Skype is minimised to tray bar (works just fine, if it is minimised to task bar).

I don't know, if this is relevant, but I have also noticed that when I have Skype minimised to tray bar then, after clicking its tray bar icon:

- it takes 2-3 seconds of wheel spinning before main Skype window displays any content,
- Skype always open on "Welcome *name* instead of the chat, I've been in recently.

I have configured my Skype to minimise to task bar on clicking "minimise" and to notification area on clicking "close" (I have disabled minimising Skype directly to notification area), if that matters.

Is there anything I can do with this? Is this some sort of bug? I must admit that it is pretty confusing and irritating that I have to close the second, not operative "copy" of main Skype windows (that appears after each click on Skype notification) to be able to interact with Skype in any way.

**Edit**: I have *Skype for Windows 10* downloaded from Microsoft via Microsoft Store app, so this is not Skype for Desktop.

Comment: Skype for Desktop version or Skype for Windows 10 downloaded from Microsoft store - which one are you using?

Comment: I have the same issue, see https://superuser.com/q/1522371/86828  I use the builtin Skype for Desktop app in Win10.

Comment: In my case both windows are fully functional. Whatever I do in one window, the other does the same. See this image https://i.imgur.com/UzU8v1q.png in first window I clicked "Notifications", then in the menu "Settings". The second window also switched to Notifications list, and then to the Settings dialog.

Comment: @Madhubala: Skype for Windows 10, please, see the edited question. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently and it turned out I had 2 copies of Skype installed.  I believe they changed the name of it recently.  If I open Add/Remove Programs and search for Skype I had 1 called "Skype" and 1 called "Skype version 8.67".  I think when it updated it didn't overwrite because of those changes.  To fix I simply uninstalled the one just called "Skype".