# Two Skype Windows

Tags: skype, skype-for-windows-10

The latest bizarreness of Skype I noticed recently:

When there is an unread message and a notification in the systray icon and I doubleclick it, two Skype windows appear. They have the same content. If I click an item, like a recent chat, both windows show the selected chat. They are like mirrors. Both fully functional.

The same thing happens when I open the Skype windows by clicking the new message notification (it is Windows 10).

I can close one window and continue using the remaining, so unlike other problems this one is not serious at all. Nevertheless comments are welcome.

OS: Windows 10 Pro, up to date
Skype Desktop App version 8.55.0.131

Comment: this doesn't perhaps sound identical, but from just earlier today, might be worth investigating - https://superuser.com/questions/1522333/doubled-skype-window-when-clicking-notification-in-windows-10

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, that looks like a duplicate, I'll inform the moderators.

Answer (score 0):

I have confronted this issue before, there are two cases:

- There is a lag and launch two Skype at the same time because clicking too quickly. This issue sometimes happens when the app support to run multiple instances.
- You have installed two Skype programs: one is downloaded from Microsoft store and one directly from Skype.com. On my computer, I run both versions for a specific reason.